# How to pass an object of a class with a string data member to another class in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class fruit{
    private:
    string name;
    int amount;
    float price;
public:
    void getData(){
        cout <<"Enter name of fruit: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);
        cout <<"Enter amount: ";
        cin >>amount;
        cout <<"Enter price: $";
        cin >>price;
        cout <<endl;
    }
    void displayData(){
        cout <<"Fruit: " <<name <<endl;
        cout <<"In stock: " <<amount <<endl;
        cout <<"Price: $" <<price <<endl;
    }
};
class seller{
public:
    void display(fruit& obj){
        cout <<"You are a seller!" <<endl <<endl;
        obj.getData();
    }
};
class buyer{
public:
    void display(fruit& obj){
        cout <<"You are a buyer!" <<endl <<endl;
        obj.displayData();
    }
};
int main(){
int userChoice;
cout <<"Welcome to shop simulator!" <<endl;
    while(true){
        cout <<"Please select anything from the following:" <<endl;
        cout <<"[0] Exit the program" <<endl;
        cout <<"[1] Seller" <<endl;
        cout <<"[2] Buyer" <<endl;
        cin >>userChoice;
        fruit obj1;
        seller obj2;
        buyer obj3;
        switch(userChoice){
            case 0:
                _Exit(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                obj2.display(obj1);
                break;
            case 2:
                obj3.display(obj1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I tried to enter a fruit and its properties in the buyer option and then tried to access it to the seller option, only the "amount" and "price" are being displayed. (I have tried using array of characters and it worked, but when I use string it doesn't work).

Comment: You should name your variables with more descriptive names other than `obj1`, `obj2`, etc.  It would make the code much easier to follow.  For example, `buyerObj`, `fruitObj`, etc.

Comment: It may be easier to write one or more constructors for fruits and call them on the Buyer class. Perhaps getData() is   not a good name for a buying process returning void

Comment: Thank you guys for these tips! I am still learning basic stuffs in C++.

Comment: And a 4th class, like Inventory would help in build a model with Buyers and Sellers of Fruits (from or into an Inventory)

Comment: I was planning to create a basic inventory system, to apply most of the OOP concept i have learned. It seems that I'm still far from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three variables:

```
        fruit obj1;
        seller obj2;
        buyer obj3;
```

are created from scratch everytime you loop. Hence the values you enter in iteration 1 are not preserved in the second iteration. The fact that you are getting `price` and `amount` correctly is just a coincidence.

To fix this quickly, just move the variables above outside the loop:

```
        fruit obj1;
        seller obj2;
        buyer obj3;
    cout <<"Welcome to shop simulator!" <<endl;
    while(true){
```

Comment: Oh, so the iteration of loops affects the creation of objects. Didn't know about that unless the object is an array. Though, thank you it fixed the error!.

Comment: Everytime you create a `{ }` pair for anything i.e `if / else`, `while / for `, it means new scope.

Comment: You can read this for more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: I have one more question, when I have tried using character arrays and it worked, it displayed what have I entered in the buyer class, do you have any explanations to this?

Comment: The reason for that could be that whatever you were storing in your variables was saved on the stack, so everytime you read the values again, they were still acessible. But beware! This is just one possible explanation. Essentially, it is *undefined behaviour*, which means it is undefined and can't be reasoned about.